# Swift multiple cell type with common variable

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I would like to have a function that return the cell that is used currently in my table view.

Here is an example of the code I'm trying to do

```
class custom1Cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var p1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var p2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var p3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}

class custom2Cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var a1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var a2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var a3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}

class EditProp: UITableViewController, ImagePickerDelegate {
    func setImageValue(image: UIImage?) {
        if image != nil {
           let cell = getCurrentCellType()
           cell.imageView.image = image!   
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mediaChooser" {
            let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as ImagePickerViewController
            destinationViewController.delegate = self

            let cell = getCurrentCellType()
            destinationViewController.image = cell.imageView.image
        }
    }
}
```

So what I want is a way to get getCurrentCellType() with the current instance of the cell I'm using. Something that would return

```
self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("custom1Cell") as custom1Cell
```

or

```
self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("custom2Cell") as custom2Cell
```

Or a way to declare all my custom1Cell, custom2Cell by heritage of a customTemplateCell: UITableViewCell that would make it possible to access the image in each.

There is only one cell at a time in my table view, plus, I got something like 9 cell type. So I want to refrain myself from doing a switch at each place I need to make an exception or access the imageView...

Is there a way to do this or did I just does it wrong?

I'm a little noob in swift. This is a school project I'm making to learn swift so be nice with your explanation. Thank in advance!

How do I link the outlet if I must do a customTemplateCell?

[image: interface with code]

Comment: Use object inheritance - each of your cells should be a subclass of a type that has the image.

Comment: @Paulw11 how do I make the outlet work? if I do something like a class template it said that I can't override the image in the custom1Cell

Comment: You don't need to override it. Outlets declared in your superclass are available in your subclass.

Comment: @Paulw11 but when I design my cell, in my table view if I make a different design for each of my cell since their other property are different, must I link the UIImageView to the same outlet in the customTemplateCell? I do I undertand this wrong?

Comment: As long as you make each custom cell inherit from the superclass and the superclass declares the outlet, the outlet will be visible when you drag to the object in Interface Builder. Don't drag to the .m/.h file in the assistant editor - drag to the cell object in the explorer on the left

Comment: @Paulw11 so basically I declare the outlet but I don't link it with the storyboard? The cell type in my storyboard keep the class custom1Cell or custom2Cell which inherit from my customTemplateCell and I should be able to access the imageView in the cell constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74142/discussion-between-paulw11-and-incognito).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give the credit to @Paulw11

The way to do this is by using a class to make the customXCell inherit the imageView outlet without overriding it int each customXCell.

Look like :

```
class Custom1Cell: CustomTemplateCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var p1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var p2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var p3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var p4: UITextField!
}

class Custom2Cell: CustomTemplateCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var a1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var a2: UITextField!
}

class CustomTemplateCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

The outlet imageView must be created in the CustomTemplateCell. To verify that it work you can hover the dot next to it in the split screen each imageView should change to overlay states.